# asp Forms Authentication across multiple applications (sub-domains)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, subdomain

I have 4 applications running on my IIS server. One of these applications is my 'main site' and there are 3 sub applications as shown in this diagram - [image]

All of these sites are in the same domain: mainSite.mydomain.com, app1.mydomain.com etc..

I would like users to be able to login to either APP 1, APP 2 or APP 3 and also be logged into the MAIN SITE, however if the user is logged into APP 1 they can't access APP 2 or APP3. So basically a user will only have access to one of the apps and the main site using the same login.

I currently use the following code however this allows the user to access all the applications with the same login :

```
<forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Login/" protection="Validation" timeout="120" path="/" domain=".mydomain.com"/>
```

and this is the code I use to create the authentication ticket:

```
        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1, user.EmailAddress,
            now,
            now.Add(mExpirationTimeSpan),
            createPersistentCookie,
            user.EmailAddress,
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        if (ticket.IsPersistent)
        {
            cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
        }
        cookie.Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL;
        cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain != null)
        {
            cookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
        }

        mHttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

How would I determine what application the user should have access to and limit the users access to the other applications? The only thing I can currently think of is somehow adding information regarding which application to use into the cookie, however would I be able to decrypt this information?

Comment: It looks to me like you're conflating the concepts of authentication and authorization. The former tells you who someone is, which is what you have here, but it's the latter that allows you to determine what someone should be able to do. You should look into ASP.Net authorization and role providers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd(v=vs.100).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab2fxh0(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes that makes sense, I completely forgot about the authorization attribute. I guess I just need to make a role for each of the applications (not the main site) and assign them to the users. Thanks!